# linq sum group by desde un list<>

Tags: c#, linq

Hola Tengo una lista de Articulos de la clase Articulo

```
public class Articulo
{
    public Int32 IdArticulo { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

pues bien, de esta lista, necesito sumar la cantidad de articulos agrupados por su Identificador de articulo, esto lo quiero ejecutar en linq.

alguna idea de como hacer esto?
Saludos y gracias

Comment: Tienes que agregar el LINQ que estás usando para la suma; este código es sólo la clase.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué sentido tiene de agrupar por el identificador? ¿No resultaría en grupos de un solo articulo en cada uno?  A menos que el identificador no es la llave primaria, pero entonces no es realmente un identificar de articulo.  Sería mejor si incluyes un ejemplo concreto con datos, además de incluir lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: sstan, tienes razon, el identificador de la tabla no es el articulo, es ua tabla sin indice, donde el articulo se puede repetir. lo que necesito es sumar todas las cantidades que hay de cada articulo, en otras palabras un select sum() group by articulo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lo poco que te estoy entendiendo ¿quieres sumar la lista en base al id?

```
public class Articulo
{
    public Int32 IdArticulo { get; set; }
    public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public int IdGrupo { get; set; }
}
var lstArticulos = ConsultaTodosArticulosDesdeBD();

var LstGrupoSumado = lstArticulos.GroupBy(l => l.IdGrupo)
                          .Select(la => 
                                new { 
                                    IdGrupo = la.Key, 
                                    NoArticulos= la.Count(),
                                    SumaCantidad = la.Sum(s => s.Cantidad), 
                                }).toList();
```

Esta es la forma de trabajar con exprecciones Lambda.

Primero se agrupan con **GroupBy()**, en este caso por su Id.
Después **Select()** se encargará de asignar cada uno de sus valores. Si te das cuenta, este GroupBy mantiene los datos como List estando dentro del Select. Y respondiendo a tu pregunta, la suma se realiza con la función **Sum()**

Comment: Hola Aaron, gracias por tu tiempo. Intente implementar tu solución, pero me da un error en la linea  IdArticulo = la.IdArticulo. 'IGrouping<int, Articulo>' no contiene una definición para 'IdArticulo' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'IdArticulo' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'IGrouping<int, Articulo>' (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: Olvide llamar a Key, que representa a los Id de los grupos. Ya actualicé

Comment: Estimado, te agradezco mucho la ayuda, funciono perfectamente. saludos